# Is it possible to resize an image that is stored in a Uint8Array without using the browser's built-in canvas implementation?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

I need to compress and rotate the image in the browser. Image sources can be *drag'n'drop* from a local user or the image can be downloaded from an URL with the same domain as the page with this script. But asking for permission to use *HTML5 canvas* doesn't fit into the design specification in any way.

The image can be in JPEG, PNG or HEIC format and in the current implementation is stored in  `Uint8Array`. Is it possible to generate a thumbnail or change image orientation without using `canvas`?

Answer (score 0):

No browser that I know of will ask for permission to use a canvas. Using a canvas is the quickest solution to do this (it's very simple indeed), and HEIC support is easy too: https://alexcorvi.github.io/heic2any/